# Binding Image.Source from BitmapImage variable using INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile, visual-studio-2015

I want to bind my CurrentWallpaper variable to Image.Source and update the Image control when it changes.
That's my code:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public BitmapImage CurrWall = new BitmapImage();
    BitmapImage CurrentWallpaper
    {
        get { return CurrWall; }
        set { CurrWall = value; OnPropertyChanged("CurrentWallpaper"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

At the Page tag I've added this DataContext attribute.

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

And that is my Image control

```
<Image x:Name="CurrentWallpaperImage" Source="{x:Bind CurrWall}"/>
```

When i try to set a new source, the Image control doesn't update.

```
StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(path);
IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
await CurrentWallpaper.SetSourceAsync(stream);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not actually assigning a new value to the CurrentWallpaper property of your page. So the OnPropertyChanged isn't triggered.

2 options, or you still use the SetSource method but after that line call the `OnPropertyChanged("CurrentWallpaper");` yourself to ensure the UI is updated.

Or create a new BitmapImage with the stream you have and fully assing that new bitmapimage to your CurrentWallpaper.

```
CurrentWallpaper = newBitmapImage;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It work perfectly. I've used this code:
    
`BitmapImage temp = new BitmapImage();
    await temp.SetSourceAsync(stream);
    CurrentWallpaper = temp;`

Answer (score 2):

At first, declare `CurrentWallpaper` as `public` property

```
private BitmapImage currentWall = new BitmapImage();
public BitmapImage CurrentWallpaper
{
    get { return currentWall; }
    set { currentWall= value; OnPropertyChanged("CurrentWallpaper"); }
}
```

At second, change `Binding` to `OneWay`

```
<Image x:Name="CurrentWallpaperImage" Source="{x:Bind CurrWall, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

If it will not work after first or second steps, try to raise event manually

```
await CurrentWallpaper.SetSourceAsync(stream);
OnPropertyChanged("CurrentWallpaper");
```